# show webpage in iframe when we click a link

Tags: html, iframe

how i can to show webpage in `iframe` when click a link?  :-?

with this code we can show `example.com` during document load. but i want to make that when click a link in this document.(This `iframe` must show in a `table`.)

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td style="width:500px;height:400px">
<iframe src='http://example.com' frameborder="0" style="width:100%;height:100%"></iframe>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the iframe a name (`<iframe name='youriframe' src='' ...></iframe>`) and add `target='youriframe'` to your link e.g.: `<a href='http://example.com/' target='youriframe'>Click!</a>`